# Set CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS options using CMake

Tags: cmake, cflags

I just want to debug some code running on Linux and I need a debug build (***[-O0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O0) [-ggdb](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-ggdb)***). So I added these things to my *[CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization)* file:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O0 -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0 -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0 -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0 -ggdb")
```

When I tried to compile I turned verbose on using `make VERBOSE=1`
And I observed the output, like this

```
... /usr/bin/c++ -D_BSD_SOURCE **-O0 -ggdb** -Wnon-virtual-dtor 
-Wno-long-long -ansi -Wundef -Wcast-align -Wchar-subscripts -Wall -W 
-Wpointer-arith -Wformat-security -fno-exceptions -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS 
-fno-check-new -fno-common -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-threadsafe-statics 
-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden **-g -O2** 
-fno-reorder-blocks -fno-schedule-insns -fno-inline ...
```

Apparently the code is compiled with "[-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g) [-O2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O2)" and this is not what I want. How can I force it to use `"-O0 -ggdb"` only?

Comment: If you want a debuggable build, just do a debug configure at the command line.  "cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug".  The resulting build will have the debug flags on for the given build system. No reason to modify the cmake file itself.  You can also send in the CMAKE_C_FLAGS value with another -D argument.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You need to set the flags *after* the `project` command in your CMakeLists.txt.

Also, if you're calling `include(${QT_USE_FILE})` or `add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})`, you should include these `set` commands after the Qt ones since these would append further flags.  If that *is* the case, you maybe just want to append your flags to the Qt ones, so change to e.g.

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0 -ggdb")
```

Comment: I did put those flags after the project command. But the output is the same.

Comment: I just noticed the `QT_NO_EXCEPTIONS` in your flags, so I've extended my answer a bit.  I'm guessing that `${QT_DEFINITIONS}` is appending the `-g -O2`.

Comment: Yes, This is it. Putting those `set` commands after the Qt ones solves the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint about the `project()` command! This solved a problem where we want set the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` for all projects via a common include but did so _after_ the project command.

Comment: I am getting "cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ggdb'"

Answer (score 35):

The easiest solution working fine for me is this:

```
export CFLAGS=-ggdb
export CXXFLAGS=-ggdb
```

CMake will append them to all configurations' flags. Just make sure to clear CMake cache.

Comment: Setting the flags in the environment like this is the only way to do it without modifying your CMakeLists.txt. Note that the environment value is only read on first configuration and is then put into the cache, so if you want to change this you need to clear the CMake cache and re-run the configure step with the new values in the env. Docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CFLAGS.html https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXXFLAGS.html

Comment: That's not "easiest", that's the only right way to do it.

Comment: Minor catch, if the generator is configuring a specific flag for a specific build type (e.g. in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ` etc.), then including it in `CXXFLAGS` (and thereby injecting it into `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`) doesn't actually suffice for passing the option to the compiler. The per build type configuration takes precedence over user input.

Comment: But just _how_ do you clear the CMake cache? If you're building into a subdir like _build, erase and recreate it.

Answer (score 19):

You must change the CMake [CFLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CFLAGS.html)/[CXXFLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXXFLAGS.html) default flags.

According to `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE={DEBUG/MINSIZEREL/RELWITHDEBINFO/RELEASE}`, put in the main `CMakeLists.txt` one of:

For C

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "put your flags")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "put your flags")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "put your flags")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "put your flags")
```

For C++

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "put your flags")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "put your flags")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "put your flags")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "put your flags")
```

This will override the values defined in [CMakeCache.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/CMake%20Cache.html).

Comment: that overrides your cmake flags that are current. so it breaks debugging unless you add the -g flag yourself (gcc)

Comment: Is there the same think using "Modern Cmake" syntax?

Answer (score 8):

On Unix systems, for several projects, I added these lines into the CMakeLists.txt and it was compiling successfully because **base** (*/usr/include*) and **local** includes (*/usr/local/include*) go into separated directories:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/local/include")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L/usr/local/lib")
```

It appends the correct directory, including paths for the C and C++ compiler flags and the correct directory path for the linker flags.

*Note: C++ compiler (c++) doesn't support -L, so we have to use [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html)*

Comment: Isnt it better to use `include_directories` instead of the `-I` flag?

Comment: Thank you so much. I was placing my linker flags in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, which caused them to be ignored. Now that I placed them in `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` based on your answer, they are working just fine.