# Why C++98 is used when specified -std=gnu++11?

Tags: c++, cmake, flags

I am trying to compile an application and I have added these lines in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
option(DISPLAY "Display images and steps" OFF)
option(TESTS "Build tests too" OFF)

if (DISPLAY)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -std=gnu++11 -DDISPLAY_IMGS")
else()
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -std=gnu++11")
endif()
```

(the lines are at the beginning of the file) I am getting an error like this:

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
error: in C++98 ‘featuresTypes’ must be initialized by constructor, not by ‘{...}’
```

Can anyone tell me why it is doing it? In fact building it in `KDevelop` works fine, but building it in terminal (`$ cmake ..` and `$ make`), it gives that error.

---

`VERBOSE=1` says:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/xxx/proj/prj1 -B/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/xxx/proj/prj1/build/CMakeFiles /home/xxx/proj/prj1/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/prj1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/prj1.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build'
cd /home/xxx/proj/prj1/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/xxx/proj/prj1 /home/xxx/proj/prj1 /home/xxx/proj/prj1/build /home/xxx/proj/prj1/build /home/xxx/proj/prj1/build/CMakeFiles/prj1.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build/CMakeFiles/optimisation.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build/CMakeFiles/prj1.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build/CMakeFiles/prj1.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target optimisation
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/optimisation.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/prj1.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/proj/prj1/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/xxx/proj/prj1/build/CMakeFiles 1
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/prj1.dir/src/cpp/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -I/home/xxx/proj/prj1/src/hpp    -o CMakeFiles/prj1.dir/src/cpp/main.cpp.o -c /home/xxx/proj/prj1/src/cpp/main.cpp
/home/xxx/proj/prj1/src/cpp/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/xxx/proj/prj1/src/cpp/main.cpp:99:33: error: in C++98 ‘featuresTypes’ must be initialized by constructor, not by ‘{...}’
```

What it should do instead?

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1` to see what is really done?

Comment: I'd wager the `-std` option is getting overridden on the command line output. Do what Marc said.

Comment: I have added the info of `VERBOSE`, how do I know that it is overwritten?

Comment: You don't find -std=c+11 in the output... Probably a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10085945

Comment: the title is totally misleading. you don't actually use that flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flags aren't making into the build command at all. So either you tried to set these flags before the `project` line in your `CMakeLists.txt`, or you're including something afterwards that is overwriting them.

You should probably move them to after any `project` line and includes, and have them append to whatever the current value is, since last flag wins.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall -std=gnu++11")
if (DISPLAY)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DDISPLAY_IMGS")
endif()
```

Comment: yes, they should be after `project`... it seems to work now. In fact the problem had appeared after adding the `TESTS` option. I think it is some kind of `undefined behaviour` if you put the `flags` before `project`