# Change compiler invocation in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

If I'm using the clang compiler in CMake, I would like to prepend the option `-cc1` to it for every possible invocation (better: only for a certain target)

I tried using

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -cc1")
```

But this wraps the invocation in quotes; consequently this doesn't get recognized as a valid command in my shell.

If I use

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -cc1)
```

then I get a semicolon between the clang invocation and the `-cc1` option. This also doesn't work.

How do I get CMake to change `/path/to/clang` into `/path/to/clang -cc1` ?

Comment: I think you can use something like [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html) so `target_compile_options(target PUBLIC "-cc1")`.

Comment: @Winestone yes that's possible, but I need to "prepend" the cc1 option after other `target_compile_options` are already set; maybe I'm trying too hard.

Comment: Try `target_compile_options(target BEFORE PUBLIC "-cc1")`.

Comment: That puts it *after* the `target_include_directories`, not right after the compiler invocation.

Comment: One hacky way I can think of is to make a script which forwards it's arguments to clang, so like `/path/to/clang -cc1 "$@"` and then set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to that.

Comment: Maybe try `string(CONCAT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} " -cc1")`?

Comment: @MassPikeMike I get `"/usr/bin/c++.exe -pedantic"` being run as a program, unfortunately.

Comment: `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` doesn't put it at the right spot ?

Comment: @luk32 I tried it and it seems to go after `target_include_directories`.

Comment: Order seems to be `${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} target_include_directories ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} target_compile_options -o output_file -c input_file`.

Comment: OK, I found out about a workaround by using the `-Xclang` option for my clang-specific needs. Feel free to give this as an answer.

Comment: @rwols You can answer your own question. It's fine. You just need to wait before you can accept it. Or you need to wait before you can post it. Either way, eventually you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround for clang-specific needs is to use the `-Xclang` compiler option, which forces the clang driver to pass the option that follows it to `clang -cc1`.

For example:

```
target_compile_options(${target} PUBLIC "-Xclang -include-pch ${output}")
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [cmake CFLAGS CXXFLAGS modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085945/cmake-cflags-cxxflags-modification)

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -cc1")
```

For a single target:

```
target_compile_options(target -cc1)
```

Comment: As seen from the comments and my question this doesn't work