# Change debug flag from -g to -ggdb3 using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, gdb

Consider the following simple C++ program:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using CMake to generate my Makefile for this project, which I then build using GNU Make and g++. My `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this (it is actually more complex, this is of course simplified):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(HelloWorld VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)
```

Everything works, but when building a debug build:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

I noticed the debugger flag that is used is `-g`. When running `make VERBOSE=1` to see what flags are used, here what shows up when compiling `main.cpp`:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++ -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/HelloWorld/main.cpp
```

Notice the `-g` flag which is put there automatically by CMake to add debugging information.

How can I change it to `-ggdb3` instead?

Comment: Related Q/A, but I would imagine that there are better ways to do this nowadays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085945/set-cflags-and-cxxflags-options-using-cmake

Comment: Note that `-g` and `-ggdb3` are mostly equivalent, except the latter records macro definitions (in a horribly inefficient way). Why do you _want_ `-ggdb3` ?

Comment: I am porting plain Makefiles to CMake. Those Makefiles had that `-ggdb3` flag, that's mostly why. If it becomes to hard to do in CMake, I might end up using the `-g` flag instead.

Comment: 1. Get linker flags with replaced `-g` option:`string(REGEX REPLACE "(^(.* )?)-g(( .*)?$)" "\\1-ggdb3\\3" RESULT "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")`. 2. Apply changes: `set_property(CACHE CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG PROPERTY VALUE ${RESULT})`

Answer (score 0):

The `-g` flags is automatically set in builtin cached variable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO`, which contains default compile options for corresponding build types. You may replace and force-set these cached variables as you like.

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "\\b-g\\b" "-ggdb3" tmp_value "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
set_property(CACHE CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG PROPERTY VALUE "${tmp_value}")
```

And at last, you may actually don't need to use `-ggdb3` at all.

Comment: It does not seem to work: I set those two lines (replacing `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` by `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`) just before my `add_executable` call, but the `-g` switch is still there, and `-ggdb3` is not. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Late to the party, but `\b` matches word boundaries; I believe the string should be `"-g\\b"` instead of `"\\b-g\\b"` (as there is no word boundary left of the hyphen).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, cmake [does not support matching word boundaries](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24297) so making this robust for all kinds of circumstances is a bit annoying. Without care, you can easily end up with replacing the (various) `-g` in the string repeatedly and/or wrongly. Also, cmake's regex engine does some [pretty stupid stuff when subgroupmatches are used](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19012) (it's always a pleasure finding your own unanswered bug reports 4 years later - but at least I supplied a workaround as well :)

I have not tested this very thoroughly but this is what I am using for now:

```
string(REGEX MATCH "^(.* )?-g( .*)?$" dummy "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
set_property(CACHE CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG PROPERTY VALUE "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}-ggdb3 -gdwarf-5 -Og${CMAKE_MATCH_2}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html

Try adding `add_compile_options(-ggdb3)` to your cmake.