# CMake ignoring compilation flags

Tags: c++, cmake, assimp

I'm trying to compile assimp using MinGW.
I run the commands

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt -G "MinGW Makefiles" -Wno-error
cmake --build .
```

but when the project builds I still get an error and the build fails.
The error:

```
In file included from C:\godijustwantittowork\include\assimp-5.2.3\contrib\unzip\ioapi.c:22:
C:\godijustwantittowork\include\assimp-5.2.3\contrib\unzip\ioapi.c: In function 'ftell64_file_func':
C:\godijustwantittowork\include\assimp-5.2.3\contrib\unzip\ioapi.h:39:21: error: implicit declaration of function 'ftello'; did you mean 'ftell'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   39 | #   define ftello64 ftello
      |                     ^~~~~~
C:\godijustwantittowork\include\assimp-5.2.3\contrib\unzip\ioapi.c:245:11: note: in expansion of macro 'ftello64'
  245 |     ret = ftello64(ioposix->file);
      |           ^~~~~~~~
C:\godijustwantittowork\include\assimp-5.2.3\contrib\unzip\ioapi.c: In function 'fseek64_file_func':
C:\godijustwantittowork\include\assimp-5.2.3\contrib\unzip\ioapi.h:40:21: error: implicit declaration of function 'fseeko'; did you mean 'fseek'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   40 | #   define fseeko64 fseeko
      |                     ^~~~~~
C:\godijustwantittowork\include\assimp-5.2.3\contrib\unzip\ioapi.c:303:9: note: in expansion of macro 'fseeko64'
  303 |     if (fseeko64(ioposix->file, offset, fseek_origin) != 0)
      |         ^~~~~~~~
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
code\CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\build.make:3049: recipe for target 'code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/__/contrib/unzip/ioapi.c.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/__/contrib/unzip/ioapi.c.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:249: recipe for target 'code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Couldn't find an answer on here so sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Ignoring "implicit declaration of function" errors has a little sense because it almost never passes the linking stage. You are better to ask why assimp is not built in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `-Wno-error` to `cmake` doesn't magically cause CMake to pass that flag to any and all compilers for any and all languages.

To pass a flag to the C compiler, put `CFLAGS=-Wno-error` on your CMake command line. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41843596/14637). You may need to clear your CMake cache.

Also note that this is unlikely to help you, because suppressing the implicit declaration warning still doesn't make those `ftello` and `fseeko` functions available.

Comment: yes you are right about the functions not being available. I had to change the source a little. However, warnings occured later down in compiling so your help was still invaluable.